# In which comic did Dhruva go to the future to defeat a villain capable of creating vacuum bubbles?

Tags: story-identification, raj-comics

I remember reading a comic in which Dhruva was called to the future because only his intelligence could defeat a villain capable of creating *Vacuum Bubbles*. Police were mostly ineffective against him because once trapped inside vacuum bubble, no one could survive and the bubble couldn't be penetrated (probably because of a force field surrounding it).

Dhruva also got trapped inside the vacuum bubble upon his first encounter with the villain, but he successfully saved himself by jumping inside water of a roadside water fountain before vacuum was fully achieved.

Can you please identify this comic?

Comment: The vacuum bubbles remind me of the bobbles in Vernor Vinge's [*The Peace War,*](http://www.amazon.com/The-Peace-War-Vernor-Vinge/dp/0765308835) without the time-stopping effect.

Comment: @Joe Bubbles of this question also don't have time-stopping effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Super Commando Dhruva (SPCL #485-H)**

Here’s the villain & vacuum bomb:

[image]

Here’s how Dhruva got trapped in a vacuum bubble:

[image]

[image]

Here’s how Dhruva survived by going under water (page 15):

[image]

P.S. Actual credit for story identification goes to user [Raj Comics Info](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/64343/raj-comics-info). I just verified it & snapped pages from the comics (Raj Comics’ app doesn’t allow taking screenshots).

P.P.S. All rights reserved to Raj Comics. This is a non-commercial fair use of the intellectual property.

Comment: I don’t think I need to translate what’s written in the comic strips as images are self explanatory for the context of the question. If anyone is curious & AI assisted translation isn’t working on image, I can translate.

Comment: Translating would make this answer more likely to be found by future querents.

Answer (score 2):

Yes I remember the name of the comic, it is "**SPCL #485 Super Commando Dhruva**". Second and the final part of "**SPCL #470 Robot**". Both comics were excellent.

Comment: [Why is this the right comic](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9444/31051)? Some images from the issue would go a long way towards making this an excellent answer